# Swift/iOS: using computed property to trigger UI update, which is better: didSet, willSet or set?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview

The UI in my iOS app is complex enough that I sometimes get confused when I should enable/disable/hide/show some buttons or views. After some thoughts, I think the app has only three states: **Idling**, **Recording**, and **Playing**.

So I created a computed property variable of the enum type `AppState`, through which I wish to observe the state changes so I can update the UI accordingly. Some of the UI changes include showing or disabling buttons as well as removing custom `UIView` objects from their super views.

```
var curState : AppState = .Idling {
    didSet {
          if newValue != oldValue {
            updateUI() // ?? better here?
          }
    }
    willSet(newValue) {
         updateUI() // ?? good here?
    }
   set {
         updateUI() // ?? good here
    }
}
```

I have been using the `set` above to call `updateUI()` method, it works fine, but I would like to know which of the three observers is better? I haven't tried `willSet` or `didSet`, but I am leaning towards using `didSet` for the reason that I can compare the `oldValue` and `newValue` before updating UI. I could be wrong, I am all ears for advice here.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're dealing with a stored property, `willSet` and `didSet` are more appropriate. If you're trying to update UI on the basis of the value you've set, then `didSet` is a logical place to do that. We only use `set` if you were using a computed property, but you're dealing with a stored property here, so that's not really relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Properties can be two types:

- Stored properties, which have a synthesized backing instance variable, and a n implicit `get` and `set` definition which you can't override. If you wish to find out when changes occur, you can use `willSet` and `didSet`.
- Computed properties, which have no backing storage, and require an explicit `get` and optionally `set`. If you want to be notified of changes, `set` is the place to do it.

You can't mix and match, that is, stored properties can't have a `get` or `set declaration, and computed properties can't have a`willSet`or`didSet` declaration.

In your case, it looks like your `appState` is a stored variable. So indeed, the correct place to put observer logic is in the `willSet` or `didSet`. There are trade-offs:

- With `willSet`, your `newValue` has to be manually passed around to whatever functions need it.
- With `didSet`, your new value is the value of the stored property itself, which all methods can access via `self`, so there's no need to manually pass it around. However, this comes at the cost of temporarily making your object state inconsistent (because a value has been set, but its updating effects haven't occurred yet), which can lead to subtle state errors you need to look out for.